# UNITY touch position to world position 2D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, touch, 2d, screen

How can I transform the touch position (On phones) to world position. For instance if my phone's screen size is 1440 by 2560 and my touch position on the phone is X 600 Y 700. How can I transform that position to world position on unity?

I need that so I can know where the user put his finger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a method that already does that for you. Have a look at [Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html).

Once you have a reference to the desired camera you can use it like this:

```
Vector2 touchPos = Input.touches[0].position;

Vector3 touchPosinWorldSpace = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(touchPos.x, touchPos.y, camera.nearClipPlane));
```