# How can I move a gameobject to where the screen was touched?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I've tried this [UNITY touch position to world position 2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26369291/unity-touch-position-to-world-position-2d) and this https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html, it mostly worked, except that the GameObject isn't exactly where the touch occurred, but a bit below and to the left of it

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that the pivot of your sprite is to the right and up of where you expect it to be, which is why it spawns low and left. You can move the pivot in the sprite editor. This is assuming your game is 2D?

Comment: yes, it is 2D, and the pivot is centered, its an editor generated circle currently

Answer (score 0):

ok, it was a pretty dumb issue, the sprite itself had an offset of from the